# node.js rows_data how to split the nested json string and push it to the same json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

NATIVE with  node.js API to get the data from the database ,
i got the data in nested JSON string format  mainly "file_Name":"3.jpg, 2.jpg, 1.jpg", 
But i want "file_Name": ["3.jpg", "2.jpg", "1.jpg"] in nested JSON array format,
i tried by using for loop and push, By using for loop i goot the array from rows_Data but i don't know w to push it to rows_Data.

Once pleas check the code if anyone know any alternative solution please help me.
,

```
rows_Data =  [{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T19:30:49.000Z",
    "name": "sankar ",
    "mobile": 9985849966,
    "picture_url": "2.jpg",
    "post_id": 4,
    "saved_name": "9.jpg",
    "file_Name": "10.jpg,9.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Working a Fine ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 3,
    "saved_name": "8.jpg",
    "file_Name": "7.jpg,8.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hello hi",
    "post_type": 1,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 2,
    "saved_name": "4.jpg",
    "file_Name": "6.jpg,5.jpg,4.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 1,
    "saved_name": "1.jpg",
    "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"
 }]



console.log(rows_Data);

var copy= []; ; 
var res_ = {};
var file_Name ={};
var result = {};

for (let i = 0; i < rows_Data.length; i++) {
     copy.push(rows_Data[i].file_Name);
     for (let j = 0; j < copy.length; j++) {
          res_[j] = copy[j].split(",");           
          for (let k = 0; k < res_.length; j++) {
               rows_Data[k].file_Name.push(res_[k]);
           } 
      } 
 }

console.log(copy); 
console.log( res_);

console.log(rows_Data)
```

required output

```
rows_Data =  [{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T19:30:49.000Z",
    "name": "sankar ",
    "mobile": 9985849966,
    "picture_url": "2.jpg",
    "post_id": 4,
    "saved_name": "9.jpg",
    "file_Name": ["10.jpg",9.jpg"]
 }, {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Working a Fine ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 3,
    "saved_name": "8.jpg",
    "file_Name": ["7.jpg","8.jpg"]
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hello hi",
    "post_type": 1,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 2,
    "saved_name": "4.jpg",
    "file_Name": ["6.jpg","5.jpg","4.jpg"]
 }, {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 1,
    "saved_name": "1.jpg",
    "file_Name": ["3.jpg", "2.jpg", "1.jpg"]
 }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()`:

```
rows_Data = rows_Data.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, file_Name: entry.file_Name.split(',') }));
```

Example:

```js
let rows_Data =  [{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T19:30:49.000Z",
    "name": "sankar ",
    "mobile": 9985849966,
    "picture_url": "2.jpg",
    "post_id": 4,
    "saved_name": "9.jpg",
    "file_Name": "10.jpg,9.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Working a Fine ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 3,
    "saved_name": "8.jpg",
    "file_Name": "7.jpg,8.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hello hi",
    "post_type": 1,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 2,
    "saved_name": "4.jpg",
    "file_Name": "6.jpg,5.jpg,4.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 1,
    "saved_name": "1.jpg",
    "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"
 }]


rows_Data = rows_Data.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, file_Name: entry.file_Name.split(',') }));

console.log(rows_Data);
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for the quick response @Sebastian your code is working perfectly for me Sir .

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) If you found my answer useful, consider marking it as an answer so future folks could benefit from it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just modify the original array, it can easily be done with

```
  rows_Data.forEach(r =>r.file_Name = r.file_Name.split(","));
```

or if you want to keep the original value, just add a new property

```
  rows_Data.forEach(r =>r.file_NameArray = r.file_Name.split(","));
```

```js
rows_Data =  [{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T19:30:49.000Z",
    "name": "sankar ",
    "mobile": 9985849966,
    "picture_url": "2.jpg",
    "post_id": 4,
    "saved_name": "9.jpg",
    "file_Name": "10.jpg,9.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Working a Fine ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-25T18:40:41.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 3,
    "saved_name": "8.jpg",
    "file_Name": "7.jpg,8.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hello hi",
    "post_type": 1,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:51:16.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 2,
    "saved_name": "4.jpg",
    "file_Name": "6.jpg,5.jpg,4.jpg"
 }, {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "post_type": 0,
    "created_date": "2019-01-21T12:50:51.000Z",
    "name": "Sivasankar",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "post_id": 1,
    "saved_name": "1.jpg",
    "file_Name": "3.jpg,2.jpg,1.jpg"
 }]

console.log(rows_Data);

rows_Data.forEach(r =>r.file_Name = r.file_Name.split(","));       

console.log(rows_Data)
```

Comment: Sir  , Thank you very much @MikNiller for the quick response your code also working fine .Thank you.